# How to shift matrix upper right triangular values to lower right

Tags: python, numpy

Given the following upper triangular matrix, I need to shift the values to the bottom as shown:

```
input_array = np.array([
    [np.nan,      1,      2,      3],
    [np.nan, np.nan,      4,      5],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,      6],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
])

result = np.array([
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,      3],
    [np.nan, np.nan,      2,      5],
    [np.nan,      1,      4,      6],
])
```

What is the best way to do this in numpy in terms of fewer lines and speed? Here is the solution I've got using meshgrid:

```
import numpy as np

n = input_array.shape[0]
j, i = np.meshgrid(np.arange(n), np.arange(n))
i2 = i - np.arange(1,n+1)[::-1]
result = input_array[i2, j]
```

Comment: You should not call it input since that is a builtin in python.

Comment: Try `array[::-1].` The syntax works as follows `array[start:stop:step]` indexes into the array starting at start, ending before you reach stop and go in steps of step. So if the step is negative you go backward.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [44]: arr = np.array([
    ...:     [np.nan,      1,      2,      3],
    ...:     [np.nan, np.nan,      4,      5],
    ...:     [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,      6],
    ...:     [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    ...: ])
```

Since there aren't any loops, your code should be fairly efficient.

```
In [45]: n = arr.shape[0]
    ...: j, i = np.meshgrid(np.arange(n), np.arange(n))
    ...: i2 = i - np.arange(1,n+1)[::-1]

In [46]: n,j,i2
Out[46]: 
(4,
 array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3]]),
 array([[-4, -3, -2, -1],
        [-3, -2, -1,  0],
        [-2, -1,  0,  1],
        [-1,  0,  1,  2]]))

In [47]: arr[i2,j]
Out[47]: 
array([[nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan,  3.],
       [nan, nan,  2.,  5.],
       [nan,  1.,  4.,  6.]])
```

It can be cleaned up a bit.  `meshgrid` doesn't need to be 'full':

```
In [50]: i,j = np.meshgrid(np.arange(n),np.arange(n),indexing='ij',sparse=True)

In [51]: i,j
Out[51]: 
(array([[0],
        [1],
        [2],
        [3]]),
 array([[0, 1, 2, 3]]))
```

Those 2 arrays `broadcast` against each other same as the full arrays.  We can produce the same `i2` with the 'reduced' `i`:

```
In [52]: i - np.arange(1,n+1)[::-1]
Out[52]: 
array([[-4, -3, -2, -1],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0],
       [-2, -1,  0,  1],
       [-1,  0,  1,  2]])
```

Or making the column `i` directly:

```
In [53]: np.arange(n)[:,None] - np.arange(1,n+1)[::-1]
Out[53]: 
array([[-4, -3, -2, -1],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0],
       [-2, -1,  0,  1],
       [-1,  0,  1,  2]])

In [54]: i2=np.arange(n)[:,None] - np.arange(1,n+1)[::-1]

In [55]: arr[i2,j]
Out[55]: 
array([[nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan,  3.],
       [nan, nan,  2.,  5.],
       [nan,  1.,  4.,  6.]])
```

Or with only one `arange`:

```
In [56]: j = np.arange(4); i2 = j[:,None]-(j+1)[::-1]; arr[i2,j]
Out[56]: 
array([[nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan,  3.],
       [nan, nan,  2.,  5.],
       [nan,  1.,  4.,  6.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
ind = (~np.isnan(input_array)).argsort(axis=0)
print(np.take_along_axis(input_array, ind, axis=0))
```

Prints:

```
[[nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan  3.]
 [nan nan  2.  5.]
 [nan  1.  4.  6.]]
```